# SQL SELECT where cell is a certain length and includes specific characters

Tags: python, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to create a SELECT statement that selects rows where NAME is max. 5 characters and the . is in the NAME.
I only want the first, so I'm including a LIMIT 1 to the statement.

I have worked with the following

```
searchstring = "."
sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE NAME LIKE %s LIMIT 1"
val = (("%"+searchstring+"%"),)
cursor.execute(sql, val)
```

But I'm not sure how to incorporate the length of NAME in my statement.

My "Table" is as follows:

```
ID     NAME
1      Jim
2      J.
3      Jonathan
4      Jack M.
5      M.S.
```

So based on the table above, I would expect row 2 and 5 to be selected.
I could select all, and loop through them. But as I only want the first, I'm thinking I would prefer a SQL statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want lenght of name? and based on that you want to pick first two results? am i right?

Comment: I want to check if the length of the NAME is max 5 characters, and I want to select the first row that fulfills both.

Comment: Have you tried using LEN() function? Be sure to delete trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CHAR_LENGTH`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/char_length/) function along with `LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE name LIKE '%.%' AND CHAR_LENGTH(name) <= 5 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try LEN() 
Select LEN(*result string*);
This will return the length of string. but this will count spaces also. Try removing it with LTRIM().

Comment: I want to add it to the SQL statement.
sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE NAME LIKE %s and LTRIM(LEN(NAME)) <= 5 LIMIT 1" <- doesn't work?

Comment: Can you please try LEN(LTRIM()) ?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL

`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE name LIKE '%.%' AND LENGTH(name) < 6 and rownum < 2`

Base on the sql language(oracle, mysql, sql server, etc) use

> > length() or char_length()
> >
> > rownum or limit